# How can I convert an ArrayBuffer to 11-Bits Values and Back again in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a 256-bit ArrayBuffer into 24 11-bit values and then back again.

Is there a simple code snippet to handle this type of operation.

I have this version, to convert it to 24 11 bit values.

```
var newBuffer = new Uint8Array(data);

var result = [];
for (var i =0, l = 24;i<l;i++){
  var index = parseInt((i*11.0)/8.0);
  var subBuffer;

  if (i==23){
    var proxyBuffer = new Uint8Array(2);
    proxyBuffer.set(newBuffer.slice(index,index+1));
    subBuffer = proxyBuffer;
  }else{
    subBuffer = newBuffer.slice(index,index+2);
  }

  var value = new Uint16Array(subBuffer.buffer);
  value = value >> (i*3)%8;
  value = value % 2048;
  result.push(value);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: But 24*11 is not 256. Where do you get the missing bits?

Comment: They can just be Zero

Comment: But then you won't get them back again...

Comment: And where should the zeros be?

Comment: At end so if the number is

-10-1010-1101-1111

and I want to break it into 4 bit values

0010,1010,1101,1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library called Uint1Array which makes everything much easier.

```
var arr = new Uint1Array(buffer);

for (let i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i+=11){
    var zero = new Uint1Array(16);
    for (let index =0, length = 11; index<length;index++){
        zero[index]=arr[i+index];
    }

    let bit16 = new Uint16Array(zero.buffer)[0];
    outPut.push(bit16);
}

console.log(outPut);

var bit256 = new Uint1Array(256);
for (let i=0, l=outPut.length;i<l;i++){
    var hold = new Uint16Array(1);
    hold[0]=outPut[i];
    let bit16 = new Uint1Array(hold.buffer);
    let bit11 = bit16.slice(0,11);

    for (let i2=0, l2=11;i2<l2;i2++){
        bit256[(i*11)+i2]=bit11[i2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bit operations can simplify the conversion process - using `parseInt` and decimal arithmetic is not an easy approach.

The concept code below uses plain arrays of octet and 11 bit values. While `Uint8Array` and `Uint16Array` types may be a better choice, creating typed arrays and/or converting an `arrayBuffer` to and from a suitable array type is not included.

```js
function ui8To11( buffer8) {
    var buffer11 = [];
    var acc = 0;
    var accBits = 0;
    function add( octet) {
       acc = (octet << accBits) | acc; 
       accBits += 8;
       if( accBits >=11) {
           buffer11.push( acc & 0x7ff);
           acc >>= 11;
           accBits -= 11;
       }
    }
    function flush() {
       if( accBits) {
           buffer11.push( acc);
       }
    }

    buffer8.forEach( add);
    flush();
    return buffer11;
}

function ui11To8( buffer11) {
    var buffer8 = [];
    var acc = 0;
    var accBits = 0;
    function add( ui11) {
       acc = (ui11 << accBits) | acc; 
       accBits += 11;
       while( accBits >= 8) {
           buffer8.push( acc & 0xff);
           acc >>= 8;
           accBits -= 8;
       }
    }
    function flush() {
       if( accBits) {
           buffer8.push( acc);
       }
    }

    buffer11.forEach( add);
    flush();
    return buffer8;
}


var buffer8 = [1,2,3];  // 8 bit values, least significant octet at index 0
console.log("octets: ", buffer8);
var buffer11 = ui8To11( buffer8);
console.log("undectets: ", buffer11);
var reconstructed = ui11To8( buffer11)
console.log("convertedBack", reconstructed);
```

There is an assumption here that the input array is little-endian, as in each entry in the input array is **more** significant than the previous entry.

Conversion between 8 and 11 bit values and back again follows a similar pattern, but pushing bits from the accumulator to the output array requires a loop when converting from a higher number of bits to a lower.

The example takes 3 x 8 bit values (24 bits in total) and produces 3 x 11 bit values (33 bits in total). Converting back 33 bits to uint8 integers produces 5 x 8 bit values ( 40 bits). You may need to add code to limit the number of integers pushed into output arrays within conversion routines or truncate output arrays returned as required.